# Why is an 'animations' property in UIImageView on custom UITableViewCell removed after calling [super prepareForReuse]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

recently, I am making a custom UITableViewCell with animatable UIImageView to play animated GIF. During making it, I found that an animation is not shown after the cell was reused.
It seems that UIImageView is affected by `[self prepareForReuse]`. When I did debugging it, I could get the following information.

```
** before calling [super prepareForReuse] **
(lldb) po self.testImageView  
<UIImageView: 0x1ab681c0; frame = (39 0; 78 61); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; animations = { UIImageAnimation=<CAKeyframeAnimation: 0x1ab77870>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ab68b60>> - (null)

** after calling [super prepareForReuse] **  
(lldb) n  
(lldb) po self.testImageView  
<UIImageView: 0x1ab681c0; frame = (39 0; 78 61); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1ab68b60>> - (null)
```

As it show, "animations = { UIImageAnimation=; };" is removed.

Fortunately, I could work around that problem by making a new instance of UIImage and setting it to UIImageView again as a workaround. For doing this workaround, it's important to re-create an instance of UIImage not to reuse an instance which is already set to UIImageView.

Anyway, what I really want to know is why `prepareForReuse` method removes the information about an animation.
Please let me know an internal reuse logic of the method which is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Upon calling `[super prepareForReuse]`, `stopAnimation` is called on `self.testImageView`. I think this is the right logic being used so that the cell can be reused. You just need to call the `[self.testImageView startAnimation]` method once the cell is prepared for reuse. You need not resort to the "workaround" method that you have mentioned.

Comment: I already had done that but not work. It seems that the information about animating got removed. so, although I called `startAnimating` after `prepareForReuse`, it didn't work.

Comment: @KyokookHwang I tried this and I don't seem to be getting the problem you mentioned. I called the `startAnimation` method on the image view after the `[super prepareForReuse]` and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: @KyokookHwang The `UIImage` instances in the imageview `animatingImages` array are also intact once I start animation.

Comment: @KyokookHwang were you ever able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I had to set the UIImageView's image property to nil in prepareForReuse(), before setting a new (or even the same) animated UIImage.